# Bash : Get first file of list with search

Tags: bash

I have a script that auto zips the public_html folder for backup purposes.

Now I'm working on a recovery script that would take the latest backup, and unzip it over public_html to do the restore.

Thing is, so I can always have the possibility of going back a few backups, I create the backup file as backup-[datetime].zip So there might be more than one .zip file in the folder.

What I found of other posts/questions were a way to get the first file of a directory, but not with a search involved.

So here is what I'm not figuring out how to do. How to get the first file that matches a search? Like in this case,  I need to find the first file alphabetically that would match backup-*.zip

Comment: `find $BACKUPDIR -maxdepth 1 -name "backup-$DATETIME.zip" | head -1` should work ok, and you should not worry about getting a _search involved_ because ti will be fast anyway.

Comment: BTW, there's some ambiguity in your question: _ first file that matches a search, but without search_? Maybe `ls -1 $BACKUPDIR/backup-$DATIME*.zip | head -1` could also work.

Comment: I need to search in a folder for any file that fits backup-*.zip, and use the one that is the first that comes out when listed alphabetically for operations. The biggest flaw with what you are advancing is that if you throw in the $DATETIME variable, well the datetime probably has changed since the backup was made. My code currently goes until seconds (so you can do more than one in the same day) but even if i only go down to the day, what happens if you find your bug only the next day? Just going for a variable doesnt work.

Comment: Also I would not be looking through thousands of files. Maybe 20. Its just if I want to take automatically the last backup I need to find what is the latest within the list.

Comment: I understand... The DATETIME in this case representes the date of the backup you are looking for, not the current date (assuming that what you want). If your dates are formatted using `YYYY-MM-DD` I don't see why using a plain ls would't work: `ls -1 $BACKUPDIR/backup-*.zip | head -1`. Or the latest: `ls -1 $BACKUPDIR/backup-*.zip | tail -n1`

Comment: I'm kinda new to bash but wouldn't ls just list them in the console? Can I use that to find the right filename, and then work from there?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `[datetime]` in your zip file name is year, then month, then day, etc (like YYYYMMDDHHmmSS), and they will sort properly. Then it won't be a problem if someone touches the timestamp on the file, because the name will handle it.

Then you can do easy things with an array.

```
list=( backup_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.zip )
latest=${list[-1]}
```

Now you can unzip `$latest`.

As an aside...
I have an app that makes an emergency backup during deployments, but only saves the latest 2 with code like this:

```
set -- $App_baseDIR/backups/*.tgz         # files in $@, can use shift
while (( $# > 2 )); do rm $1; shift; done # remove all but most recent 2
```

as long as you can trust your filenames to sort properly, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Comments were getting too long so I'd better give you a more complete answer:

```
[16:46:43]~/devel/backups>
❯ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ichramm ichramm 0 2021-07-25 00:00 backup-2021-07-25.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ichramm ichramm 0 2021-07-26 00:00 backup-2021-07-26.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ichramm ichramm 0 2021-07-27 00:00 backup-2021-07-27.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ichramm ichramm 0 2021-07-28 00:00 backup-2021-07-28.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ichramm ichramm 0 2021-07-29 00:00 backup-2021-07-29.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ichramm ichramm 0 2021-07-30 00:00 backup-2021-07-30.zip
[16:46:43]~/devel/backups>
❯ MYFILE=$(ls -1 backup-* | head -1) && echo "Oldest: $MYFILE"
Oldest: backup-2021-07-25.zip
[16:46:51]~/devel/backups>
❯ MYFILE=$(ls -1 backup-* | tail -1) && echo "Newest: $MYFILE"
Newest: backup-2021-07-30.zip
```

As you can see, I have several backup files in the folder `~/devel/backups`.

The following code:

```
MYFILE=$(ls -1 backup-* | head -1)
```

sets `$MYFILE` with the name of the oldest backup and

```
MYFILE=$(ls -1 backup-* | tail -1)
```

sets `$MYFILE` with the name of the newest backup file.

You should't worry about whether `ls` will list all the files or not, you just have to worry about selecting the correct one from that list.